# JOIN or Correlated subquery with exists clause, which one is better

Tags: sql

```
select * 
from ContactInformation c 
where exists (select * from Department d where d.Id = c.DepartmentId )

select * 
from ContactInformation c 
inner join Department d on c.DepartmentId = d.Id
```

Both the queries give out the same output, which is good in performance wise  join or correlated sub query with exists clause, which one is better.

Edit :-is there alternet way for joins , so as to increase performance:-
In the above 2 queries i want info from dept as well as contactinformation tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the EXISTS clause because you may need DISTINCT for a JOIN for it to give the expected output. For example, if you have multiple `Department` rows for a `ContactInformation` row.

In your example above, the `SELECT *`:

- means different output too so they are not actually equivalent
- less chance of a index being used because you are pulling all columns out

Saying that, even with a limited column list, they will give the same plan: until you need DISTINCT... which is why I say "EXISTS"

Comment: Edit :-is there alternet way for joins , so as to increase performance:- In the above 2 queries i want info from dept as well as contactinformation tables

Answer (score 5):

You need to measure and compare - there's no golden rule which one will be better - it depends on too many variables and things in your system.

In SQL Server Management Studio, you could put both queries in a window, choose `Include actual execution plan` from the Query menu, and then run them together.

[image]

You should get a comparison of both their execution plans and a percentage of how much of the time was spent on one or the other query. Most likely, both will be close to 50% in this case. If not - then you know which of the two queries performs better.

You can learn more about SQL Server execution plans (and even download a free e-book) from [Simple-Talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/search/default.aspx?search=execution+plan) - highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that either you meant to add the `DISTINCT` keyword to the `SELECT` clause in your second query (or, less likely, a Department has only one Contact).

First, always start with 'logical' considerations. The `EXISTS` construct is arguably more intuitive so, all things 'physical' being equal, I'd go with that.

Second, there will be one day when you will need to ports this code, not necessarily to a different SQL product but, say, the same product but with a different optimizer. A decent optimizer should recognise that both are equivalent and come up with the same ideal plan. Consider that, in theory, the `EXISTS` construct has slightly more potential to short circuit.

Third, test it using a reasonably large data set. If performance isn't acceptable, start looking at the 'physical' considerations (but I suggest you always keep your 'logically-pure' code in comments for the forthcoming day when the perfect optimizer arrives :)

Answer (score 1):

Your first query should output Department columns, while the second one should not.

If you're only interested in ContactInformation, these queries are equivalent.  You could run them both and examine the query execution plan to see which one runs faster.  For example, on MYSQL, `where exists` is more efficient with nullable columns, while `inner join` performs better if neither column is nullable.