# Spark sql "Futures timed out after 300 seconds" when filtering

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I get an exception when doing what seems to be simple spark sql filtering job:

```
    someOtherDF
      .filter(/*somecondition*/)
      .select($"eventId")
      .createOrReplaceTempView("myTempTable")

    records
      .filter(s"eventId NOT IN (SELECT eventId FROM myTempTable)")
```

Any idea how I can solve this ?

Note:

- someOtherDF contains between ~1M and 5M rows after filtering and eventId are guids.
- records contains between 40M and 50M rows.

Error:

```
Stacktrace:

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResultInForkJoinSafely(ThreadUtils.scala:215)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeBroadcast$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeBroadcast(SparkPlan.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec.doExecute(BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec.scala:343)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
        at ...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResultInForkJoinSafely(ThreadUtils.scala:212)
    ... 84 more
```

Comment: we have a similar issue of "futures timed out" (SPARK-20784), but with a very different query pattern. What type of deployment are you using ? YARN-client ? other ? Are the involved datasets cached ?

Comment: In this particular scenario, datasets were not cached since it is single pass transformation.  Theses tests were running on yarn; client or cluster mode didn't matter if I recall correctly.

Comment: I finally found the cause in my case, it was due to a OOM on the driver (which was most of the time silent, just saw the exception by chance in the flow of logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pieces from:
1) [How to exclude rows that don't join with another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560471/how-to-exclude-rows-that-dont-join-with-another-table)
2) [Spark Duplicate columns in dataframe after join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258506/spark-duplicate-columns-in-dataframe-after-join)

I can solve my problem using a left outer join like this:

```
    val leftColKey = records("eventId")
    val rightColKey = someOtherDF("eventId")
    val toAppend: DataFrame = records
      .join(someOtherDF, leftColKey === rightColKey, "left_outer")
      .filter(rightColKey.isNull) // Keep rows without a match in 'someOtherDF'. See (1)
      .drop(rightColKey) // Needed to discard duplicate column. See (2)
```

Performance is really good and it does not suffer from the 'Future timed out' problem.

**EDIT**

As a colleague pointed out to me, the "leftanti" join type is more efficient.