# SQL WITH AS statements in Ecto Subquery

Tags: sql, elixir, common-table-expression, ecto

I have an SQL query that using the PostgreSQL `WITH AS` to act as an `XOR` or "Not"  Left Join. The goal is to return what is in unique between the two queries.

In this instance, I want to know what users have transactions within a certain time period AND do not have transactions in another time period. The SQL Query does this by using `WITH` to select all the transactions for a certain date range in `new_transactions`, then select all transactions for another date range in `older_transactions`. From those, we will select from `new_transactions` what is **NOT** in `older_transactions`.

My Query in SQL is :

```
/* New Customers */
WITH new_transactions AS (
       select * from transactions
       where merchant_id = 1 and inserted_at > date '2017-11-01'
     ), older_transactions AS (
        select * from transactions
        where merchant_id = 1 and inserted_at < date '2017-11-01'
     )
SELECT * from new_transactions
WHERE user_id NOT IN (select user_id from older_transactions);
```

I'm trying to replicate this in Ecto via Subquery. I know I can't do a `subquery` in the `where:` statement, which leaves me with a `left_join`. How do I replicate that in Elixir/Ecto?

What I've replicated in Elixir/Ecto throws an `(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Ecto.Queryable not implemented for [%Transaction....`

Elixir/Ecto Code:

```
 def new_merchant_transactions_query(merchant_id, date) do
    from t in MyRewards.Transaction,
    where: t.merchant_id == ^merchant_id and fragment("?::date", t.inserted_at) >= ^date
  end

  def older_merchant_transactions_query(merchant_id, date) do
    from t in MyRewards.Transaction,
    where: t.merchant_id == ^merchant_id and fragment("?::date", t.inserted_at) <= ^date

  end

  def new_customers(merchant_id, date) do
    from t in subquery(new_merchant_transactions_query(merchant_id, date)),
    left_join: ot in subquery(older_merchant_transactions_query(merchant_id, date)),
    on: t.user_id == ot.user_id,
    where: t.user_id != ot.user_id,
    select: t.id
  end
```

Update:

I tried changing it to `where: is_nil(ot.user_id),` but get the same error.

Comment: [`LEFT JOIN <some_table> ON <related_keys> WHERE <some_table.column> IS NULL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560471/how-to-exclude-rows-that-dont-join-with-another-table).  I don't know how to write that in ecto, though.  Note that your current final `WHERE` seems to be a condition that would turn your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into a (regular) `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I tried changing it to `where: is_nil(ot.user_id),` and get the same error. It may be something else

Comment: Please include the complete error, it looks like it looks like a list of transactions has already been read from the Repo??

Comment: Full Error: https://gist.github.com/cdesch/8defe0d38b69c7ce905cf534cd6ece0e

Comment: Please include the source for `new_merchant_transactions` code used in the gist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maybe should be a comment instead of an answer, but it's too long and needs too much formatting so I went ahead and posted this as an answer. With that out of the way, here we go.

What I would do is re-write the query to avoid the Common Table Expression (or CTE; this is what a `WITH AS` is really called) and the `IN()` expression, and instead I'd do an actual JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM transactions n
LEFT JOIN transactions o ON o.user_id = n.user_id and o.merchant_id = 1 and o.inserted_at < date '2017-11-01'
WHERE n.merchant_id = 1 and n.inserted_at > date '2017-11-01'
    AND o.inserted_at IS NULL
```

You might also choose to do a `NOT EXISTS()`, which on Sql Server at least will often produce a better execution plan.

This is probably a better way to handle the query anyway, but once you do that you may also find this solves your problem by making it much easier to translate to ecto.