# Sequelize receiving empty array while filtering with association at top level

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Sequelize version: *6.6.2*

### Context

I have 3 models: **User**, **Food**, **UserFoods**. They have a Super Many-to-Many relationship between them using the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html#through-tables-versus-normal-tables-and-the--quot-super-many-to-many-association-quot-).

```js
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  username: DataTypes.STRING,
});

const Food = sequelize.define('food', {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
});

const UserFoods = sequelize.define('user_foods', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  status: DataTypes.INTEGER,
});

User.belongsToMany(Food, { through: UserFoods });
Food.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserFoods });
User.hasMany(UserFoods);
UserFoods.belongsTo(User);
Food.hasMany(UserFoods);
UserFoods.belongsTo(Food);
```

The `status` column in UserFoods will receive a number when adding a food to a user that will be used to create the user food lists (favorite, good, suck...).

This way I can query like this:

```js
const foods = await UserFoods.findAll({
  where: { userId: req.userId, status: 1 },
  include: Food,
});
```

### The Problem

Now I'm trying to query all Foods that **are not** in any of the user lists. Im doing the following:

```js
const foods = await Food.findAll({
  where: {
    "$user_foods.userId$": { [Op.not]: req.userId },
  },
  include: {
    model: UserFoods,
    duplicating: false,
  },
  limit: 10,
});

// output foods: []
```

Why am I receiving an empty array?

If I change the `Op.not` to `Op.eq` it will return all the foods that belongs to that user, so why doesn't work the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Op.ne` insead of `Op.not`

```
where: {
    "$user_foods.userId$": { [Op.ne]: req.userId },
  },
```

Comment: I'm getting the same empty array with `Op.ne`

Answer (score 0):

I found out a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560471/how-to-exclude-rows-that-dont-join-with-another-table) about SQL Joins and it suggests using null on the key of the second table.

```js
const foods = await Food.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
      { "$user_foods.userId$": { [Op.ne]: req.userId } },
      { "$user_foods.userId$": { [Op.is]: null } },
    ]
  },
  include: {
    model: UserFoods,
    duplicating: false,
  },
  limit: 10,
});
```

So for the Foods that have users associated, return only foods that are not associated with the current user.

**OR**

Return all Foods that does not have any associated user.

This is working but i'm not sure if is the best way to do it since I don't have much experience with Sequelize and SQL.