# nested exists clauses vs adjacent exists clauses

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Can someone please tell me which of this 2 querys is better than the other and why?
Should I use a join instead?

```
select * from grandChildTable gct
where exists(
    select * from childTable ct
    where some condition
    and gct.parentId = ct.Id
    and exists(
        select * from Table t
        where some other condition
        and ct.parentId = t.Id))

select * from grandChildTable gct
where exists(
    select * from childTable ct
    where some condition
    and gct.parentId = ct.Id)
and exists(
    select * from Table t
    where some other condition
    and gct.grandParentId = t.Id)
```

NOTES:
The `GrandChildTable` has the IDs for both the `ChildTable` and `Table` because the IDs are compound.

The tables doesn't have references to any of the others.

The relationships between the tables are:

```
GrandChild to Child
n:1

Child to Table
n:1
```

Comment: You need to run it against your data as there is no absolute answer.  Indexes also come into play - big time.  I like joins as for me they are easier to read and most of the time have the best performance.

Comment: BalamBalam: can you prove that JOINs are more efficient? I state EXISTS is more efficient: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2177346/27535 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/3305891/27535 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/6966023/27535 etc

Comment: @GBN Why do you feel I need to prove JOINs are more efficient?  I did not assert that JOINs are more efficient.  Read the comment "there is no absolute answer".  OK so your experience is that EXISTS is typically faster.  I am not doubting your data nor am I asking you to prove EXISTS is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case (comparing to parent tables where you have less rows then the child) there may little difference using JOINs. However EXISTS is typically quicker and proven so.

I would also expect the optimiser to generate identical plans for the 2 EXISTS based ones: [examine the query plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx) and see if there are any differences (also [this Red Gate link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)). If not, go for readability.